# Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens - google - python

Tags: python, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

**Context**

- I'm migrating to Google's new auth solution that doesn't require 3rd party cookies [using the following guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code):
- My app is a frontend built in Vue.js and a backend in Python (Flask).

**Problem**

Once I receive the Authorization token from Google (looks something like `4/0AdQt...bg`), I'm unable to exchange it for a refresh & access token.

For Python, the official Google documentation only [shows an example that uses Flask](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) (using the `Flow` object) to request the token and verify it.

I've tried to build a simple POST request with postman

```
import requests

url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

payload='code=4%2F...bg&client_id=92...cac42tg.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=hw...u8D&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fco...pp&grant_type=authorization_code'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

But I get the following unhelpful `400 Bad Request` response

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I tried to change the different form parameters and got different errors (`The OAuth client was not found.`, `Unauthorized`, `invalid_request`, ...) so most likely the error is in the actual `code`.

If anyone has faced a similar issue, I'd love some help!

Comment: It's been a while since I tried google oauth2 but make sure the redirect URLs are exactly the same. Also a code expires after a while so try getting another one.

Comment: invalid_grant means the code is not valid. The code can only used once and immediately. You can't just store it and use it later.